# How to prove a function is a tautology?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If we have the function P(n): 2 | (2n-1), how could we prove that P(k) -> P(k+1) is a tautology?

Comment: I don't even know where to start.

Comment: $\;P(n)\;$ is false since $\;2 \not \mid 2n-1\;$  therefore $\;P(k) \implies \text{anything}\;$ is always true.

Comment: @dxiv does $n$ have to be an integer though?

Comment: n does have to be an integer, sorry I left that out.

Comment: @Archr Your answer makes the same assumption (how else do you define $\,2 \mid 2k-1\,$).

Comment: Well, I would have thought the function was true for $n=.5+z$ , $z \in \mathbb{N}$, and false for other inputs. But considering the revision, your answer is definitely cleaner and better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P(k)$. That is, $2|(2k-1)$. By the definition of | we have $2x = 2k-1$ for some integer $x$. We perform some algebraic manipulations: 
$$2x  = 2k-1$$ 
$$2x +2 = 2k+1$$ 
$$2(x+1) = 2k+1$$
$$2(x+1) = 2k+1 +1 - 1$$
$$2(x+1) = 2k+2 - 1$$
$$2(x+1) = 2(k+1) - 1$$
$x$ is an integer, so $x+1$ is also an integer. Thus, we have shown that for some integer $y$, $2y=2(k+1)-1$. This is $P(k+1)$, so $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$.